# google maps reverse geocoding xml problem

Tags: xml, google-maps

i need to extract data from an xml file but have a problem with a sintax for an addressline

im using this

$node->AddressDetails->Country->SubAdministrativeArea->AddressLine;

if also tried

$node->AddressDetails->Country->SubAdministrativeArea->PostalCode->AddressLine;

this is the result , on P3 (La Julia )

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=18.4632,-69.9296&output=xml

I have other fields working, so i know its not the code to grab the xml.. its in the link to grab the addressline

Answer (score 1):

Note that Google have deprecated their V2 API, so you might want to have a look at their new V3 API:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

For example:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=18.4632,-69.9296&sensor=false

This XML might be easier to parse as it is flatter structure?